# How to generate a list of all combinations of 14 numbers into two separate groups?

Tags: r, list, combinations, probability

So I am trying to create a list of all combinations of 14 numbers that have been split into two separate groups. For example, the beginning of this list may look like:

| Group X | Group Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 |
| 1, 2 | 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 |
| 1, 2, 3 | 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 |

And so forth. This list would consist of 16384 possible combinations of these 14 numbers when split into two groups. (2^14) Any ideas on how to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try (for `2^3` cases)

```
x <- expand.grid(replicate(3, c(T,F), simplify = F))
apply(x, 1, function(x){list(group1 = c(1:3)[x], group2 = c(1:3)[!x])})

[[1]]
[[1]]$group1
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]]$group2
numeric(0)


[[2]]
[[2]]$group1
[1] 2 3

[[2]]$group2
[1] 1


[[3]]
[[3]]$group1
[1] 1 3

[[3]]$group2
[1] 2


[[4]]
[[4]]$group1
[1] 3

[[4]]$group2
[1] 1 2


[[5]]
[[5]]$group1
[1] 1 2

[[5]]$group2
[1] 3


[[6]]
[[6]]$group1
[1] 2

[[6]]$group2
[1] 1 3


[[7]]
[[7]]$group1
[1] 1

[[7]]$group2
[1] 2 3


[[8]]
[[8]]$group1
numeric(0)

[[8]]$group2
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code accomplishes something close to what you are requesting.  The results are stored in the non-zero entries of the matrices "group1" and "group2" by corresponding row, so you may need to alter the code in order to render the results in a form that is useful for your purposes.

The output is shown as it was returned from the R console; the truncated data tables at the end illustrate the form of the output.

```r
# Written in R version 4.1.1
require(data.table)

group1 = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 16384, ncol = 14, byrow = T)
group2 = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 16384, ncol = 14, byrow = T)
a = 1:14
count = 1
for(i in 0:14){
  nf = data.frame(combn(a,i))
    for(j in 1:dim(nf)[2]){
        g1 = c(nf[,j])
        if(length(g1) > 0){
          group1[count,1:length(g1)] = g1
          }
          g2 = a[-g1]
          if(length(g2) > 0){
            group2[count,1:length(g2)] = g2
            }
          if(i == 0 & j == 1){
            group2[count,1:14] = 1:14
            }
            count = count + 1
             }}
data.table(group1)
```

```r
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
# 1:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2:  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3:  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4:  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 5:  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# ---                                               
# 16380:  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 16381:  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 16382:  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 16383:  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 16384:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
```

```r
data.table(group2)
```

```r
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
# 1:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
# 2:  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 3:  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 4:  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# 5:  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14   0
# ---                                               
# 16380:  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 16381:  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 16382:  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 16383:  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
# 16384:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

```r
print(paste("count = ",count - 1))
```

```r
# [1] "count =  16384"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `combn` like below

```
v <- 1:14
res <- do.call(
  c,
  lapply(
    c(0, seq_along(v)),
    function(k) {
      combn(v, k, function(x) list(grp1 = x, grp2 = v[!v %in% x]),
        simplify = FALSE
      )
    }
  )
)
```

and we will see

```
> length(res)
[1] 16384


> head(res)
[[1]]
[[1]]$grp1
integer(0)

[[1]]$grp2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


[[2]]
[[2]]$grp1
[1] 1

[[2]]$grp2
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


[[3]]
[[3]]$grp1
[1] 2

[[3]]$grp2
 [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


[[4]]
[[4]]$grp1
[1] 3

[[4]]$grp2
 [1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


[[5]]
[[5]]$grp1
[1] 4

[[5]]$grp2
 [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14


[[6]]
[[6]]$grp1
[1] 5

[[6]]$grp2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```